# add data dosen't appear in Firebase Realtime

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I actually I'm trying to upload an image to Firestorage then add URL to Firebase database.
my code is run fine and successfully upload the selected image to storage under specific userId  my problem is when adding data to database it's executed successfully as shown in logcat but when I check in database added data is not appear I checked the permission as well security role of Firebase it's set right but still add data to nodes not appear is any error in my code or what?

```
private void UpoloadImageTofirebaseStorage() {
    user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("users").child(user_id);
    if (imagePath != null) {
        //   final StorageReference imageRef = mStorageRef.child("users").child(user_id);
        UploadTask uploadTask = mStorageRef.putFile(imagePath);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Store image in storage:failure", e);
            }
        });
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Task<Uri> downloadUrl = mStorageRef.getDownloadUrl();
                Log.i(TAG,"Image Added "+ downloadUrl);
                downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        profileImageURL = uri.toString();
                        Log.i(TAG,"File Location"+  profileImageURL);
                        SaveUserToFirebaseDatabase( profileImageURL);

                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
} 


  

// add user info to datadase
private void SaveUserToFirebaseDatabase(String profileImageURL)
        {
           user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            CreationDate = new  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            MyUsers user = new MyUsers(FullName,Password,EmailAddress,Gender, profileImageURL,CreationDate);
            //add user to profile & all
            DatabaseReference  mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/profile").child(user_id);
         
            mDatabase.setValue(user).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.i(TAG," mDatabase unable to add data"+ e);
                }
            });
         
                   
            Toast.makeText( UserSignup.this, "your information Added Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

[image: here is what appear in logcat after run code]

all added data appear in logcat but still not appear as node in firebase

Comment: If you add a `addOnSuccessListener` to the `mDatabase.setValue(user)` call too, does that get called?

Comment: yeah it's called @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I'm not sure I understand what's going wrong in that case, as the `onSuccess` handler of a database write is only called after the data has been committed on the server. Are you sure you're looking in the right place? Also: can you edit your question to show the updated code, and its output?

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen I update my question with what I get in logcat

Comment: Thanks. Can you also update the code to show your `onSuccess` handler?

Answer (score 2):

You could be missing the following `push()` method. Try this:

```
mDatabase.push().setValue(user)
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write -- is where i got the answer

Comment: OP is actually already creating a path to a user-specific node with `getReference("users/profile").child(user_id)`. While `push()` is a good way to generate unique IDs, using the UID to identify user profiles is an even better one here. :)

Comment: ahh I see, thank you! I recall you helping me a lot from when I was working on Firebase haha